# Setting up Git osxkeychain error

Tags: git, terminal

I'm setting up Git and I am following http://lifehacker.com/5983680/how-the-heck-do-i-use-github along with the regular tutorial Git provides.

My problem is I don't want to have to type in my password each time so I am following this tutorial and when I arrive at the step where you input the `git config —global credential.helper osxkeychain` command, I get the error

```
error: key does not contain a section: —global.
```

If I *ls* it, it shows the `git-credential-osxkeychain` in my current directory but I'm not sure what this error means and how to fix it... Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried the [GitHub guide for ssh passphrases on Mac/OS X](https://help.github.com/articles/working-with-ssh-key-passphrases#mac-osx-keychain) instead?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You probably typed '`—`' (the [long dash](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dash)) instead of the expected [double hyphen](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyphen)

```
 git config --global credential.helper osxkeychain
```

Note the '`--`' in front of `global`, instead of '`—`'

The [lifehacker blog posts](http://lifehacker.com/) incrrectly replace the '`--`' by '`—`'.