# Rebase actions not accepted

Tags: git

I am currently rebasing my local branch with a remote branch considering I have my own changes. But after fetching changes from other teammates, my `git rebase --continue` doesn't work. I tried to escape it by undoing changes and resetting my local branch to the remote branch. I even tried `git rebase --abort`.

The problem I see is that `git` only returns help commands about rebase and its usage. I checked the spelling, and it's fine. I even copied it directly from the guide that appeared, but git doesn't accept my commands. Must be wrong with configuration somewhere? Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1):

Try and use in a CMD session a [simplified PATH](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52287695/6309)

```
set PATH=C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\
set GH=C:\Git
set PATH=%GH%\bin;%GH%\usr\bin;%GH%\mingw64\bin;%PATH%
```

(replace `C:\Git` by your Git installation path: the folder above the result of `where git`)

If you are not on Windows, you can adapt the same idea for Linux, keeping only a minimal `$PATH`.

Check for aliases, and for `git config -l | grep alias`.

Also type `git rebase --continue` or `git rebase ---abort` ([or `git rebase --quit`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41363262/6309)) without copying them, in order to avoid [copying a long dash](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22281007/6309) or a [minus](https://stackoverflow.com/a/170148/6309).

Comment: Thank you for this, good sir! I'll give a try later. Once it worked, I'll mark this as the accepted answer.

Comment: Well, it didn't totally fix the issue. But, good news is I was able to commit and push my changes. Though, running `git rebase --abort || --continue` is still not working. It's weird that whenever I run `git status`, `You are currently rebasing branch 'new-features' on 'fds7asdf'` is still showing, and I've already been able to checkout to other branches. LOL. Anyway, thanks again.

Comment: Since, I have no more current changes, I just cloned a new repo so I won't have to deal with that anymore. Of course, I cannot rebase again. That's the sad part.

Comment: @sandddyyyy git rebase --quit would have removed the rebase in progress status.